# Yesod crashes with heap corruption

Tags: haskell, yesod

I installed a fresh version of the Haskell Platfrom and Yesod (from Stackage Nightly) on Windows 7.
During development the yesod application crashes.

The Windows Eventlog has the following entry:

```
Application name: yesod.exe, version: 0.0.0.0
Module name: ntdll.dll, версия: 6.1.7601.18247
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Exception offset: 0x00000000000c4102
Application path: C:\Users\Bet\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin\yesod.exe
Module Path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
```

The error occurs when I send a request to the server. No log messages in console. How to detect why yesod crashes?

Comment: I am wondering, which error?

Comment: My yesod server application is running. I send request to server.In console no log message. I dont't know what's going on. How to diagnose the error?

Comment: The error occurs not always, from time to time.

Comment: What should I do to find out where the error occurs?

Comment: Can you make a small, repeatable example?  What's the minimal amount of code you can write to cause this error, and what is your full setup?  It might be a problem with your OS setup, your hardware, or some other small thing.  Intermittent bugs like this are really hard to track down, and virtually impossible with the sparse information you've provided.

Comment: Error in Windows Event Viewer:
Application name: yesod.exe, version: 0.0.0.0
Module name: ntdll.dll, версия: 6.1.7601.18247
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Exception offset: 0x00000000000c4102
Application path: C:\Users\Bet\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin\yesod.exe
Module Path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll

Comment: Error code 0xc0000374 is heap curruption.

Comment: Probably it is ghc bug? https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7919